# bvCase Insensitive Regex Replacement From Dictionary

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I'm sorry, but I haven't been able to find a working solution from any of the solutions Google's been giving me (a couple of "recipes" on some site were pretty close, but way old and I haven't found something that gives me the result I'm looking for.

I'm renaming files, so I have a function that spits out the filename, for this I'm just using 'test_string's:
So, all the dots, (and underscores) and stuff are removed first--since those are the most common thing all these professors do differently and makes all this stuff impossible to deal with (or look at) without removing.
5 Examples:

```
test_string_1 = 'legal.studies.131.race.relations.in.the.United.States.'
```

'legal.studies' --> 'Legal Studies'

```
test_string_2 = 'mediastudies the triumph of bluray over hddvd'
```

'mediastudies' --> 'Media Studies', 'bluray' --> 'Blu-ray, 'hddvd' --> 'HD DVD'

```
test_string_3 = 'computer Science Microsoft vs unix'
```

'computer Science' --> 'Computer Science', 'unix' --> 'UNIX'

```
test_string_4 = 'Perception - metamers dts'
```

'Perception' would already be good (but who cares), big picture is they want to keep the audio information in there, so 'dts' --> DTS

```
test_string_5 = 'Perception - Cue Integration - flashing dot example aac20 xvid'
```

'aac20' --> 'AAC2.0', 'xvid' --> 'XviD'

Currently I'm running this through something like:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'(?i)Legal(\s|-|)Studies', 'Legal Studies', re.sub(r'(?i)Sociology', 'Sociology', re.sub(r'(?i)Media(\s|-|)Studies', 'Media Studies', re.sub(r'(?i)UNIX', 'UNIX', re.sub(r'(?i)Blu(\s|-|)ray', 'Blu-ray', re.sub(r'(?i)HD(\s|-|)DVD', 'HD DVD', re.sub(r'(?i)xvid(\s|-|)', 'XviD', re.sub(r'(?i)aac(\s|-|)2(\s|-|\.|)0', 'AAC2.0', re.sub(r'(?i)dts', 'DTS', re.sub(r'\.', r' ', original_string.title()))))))))))
```

I have them all smushed together on one line; because I'm not changing/updating it much and (the way my brain/ADD works) it's easier to have it as minimal/out-of-the-way as possible while I'm doing other things once I'm not messing with this part anymore.

So, with my example:

```
new_test_string_1 = 'Legal Studies 131 Race Relations In The United States'
new_test_string_2 = 'Media Studies The Triumph Of Blu-ray Over HD DVD'
new_test_string_3 = 'Computer Science Microsoft Vs UNIX'
new_test_string_4 = 'Perception - Metamers DTS'
new_test_string_5 = 'Perception - Cue Integration - Flashing Dot Example AAC2.0 XviD'
```

However, as I have more and more of these it's really starting to become the kind of thing I want to have a dictionary or something for--I don't want to blow up the code to anything crazy, but I'd like to be able to add new replacements as real life examples come up that need to be added (for example, there are a lot of audio codecs/containers/whatevers out there, and it looks like I might have to just throw them all in).  I have no opinion about the method used by this master-list/dictionary/whatever.

Big picture: I'm fixing spaces and underscores in the filenames, replacing a bunch of shit with capitalization stuff (at the moment, universally title-casing it with the exception of the re.subs I'm making, which deal with plenty of cases where the capitalization isn't perfect and there may or may not be a space, dash, or dot in the input that the output should have).

Similarly, a one-liner, unnamed (such as lambda) function would be preferable.

P.S.
Sorry for some of the weirdness and some of the initial lack of clarity.  One of the problems here is in my major/studies most of the stuff is actually pretty straight-forward, it's other classes that need all the Blu-ray, HD DVD, DTS, AAC2.0, XviD, etc.

Comment: Can you provide some more sample text? Like at least 3.

Comment: Your example actually returns `'Legal Studies 131 race relations in the U S '` not `'Legal Studies 131 race relations'`

Comment: @Jack Sorry, I've done that twice now and both times I thought about it before submitting the question and decided more examples would make it worse for the people trying to help me instead of better--I'll have to make sure I have lots the next time I ask a question.  =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def string_fix(filename, dict):
    filename = filename.replace('.', ' ')
    for key, val in dict.items():
        filename = re.sub(key, val, filename, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return filename

dict = {
         r'Legal[\s\-_]?Studies' : 'Legal Studies',
         r'Media[\s\-_]?Studies' : 'Media Studies',
         r'dts' : 'DTS',
         r'hd[\s\-_]?dvd': 'HD DVD',
         r'blu[\s\-_]?ray' : 'Blu-ray',
         r'unix' : 'UNIX',
         r'aac[\s\-_]?2[\.]?0' : 'AAC2.0',
         r'xvid' : 'XviD',
         r'computer[\s\-_]?science' : 'Computer Science'
     }

string_1 = 'legal.studies.131.race.relations.in.the.United.States.'
string_2 = 'mediastudies the triumph of bluray over hddvd'
string_3 = 'computer Science Microsoft vs unix'
string_4 = 'Perception - metamers dts'
string_5 = 'Perception - Cue Integration - flashing dot example aac20 xvid'

print(string_fix(string_1, dict))
print(string_fix(string_2, dict))
print(string_fix(string_3, dict))
print(string_fix(string_4, dict))
print(string_fix(string_5, dict))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> def string_fix(text,substitutions):
        text_no_dots = text.replace('.',' ').strip()
        for key,substitution in substitutions.items():
            text_no_dots = re.sub(key,substitution,text_no_dots,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        return text_no_dots

>>> teststring = 'legal.studies.131.race.relations.in.the.U.S.'
>>> d = {
     r'Legal(\s|-|)Studies' : 'Legal Studies', 
     r'Sociology'           : 'Sociology', 
     r'Media(\s|-|)Studies' : 'Media Studies'
}
>>> string_fix(teststring,d)
'Legal Studies 131 race relations in the U S'
```

And here is a much better way of doing it without a dictionary

```
>>> teststring = 'legal.studies.131.race.relations.in.the.U.S.'
>>> def repl(match):
        return ' '.join(re.findall('\w+',match.group())).title()

>>> re.sub(r'Legal(\s|-|)Studies|Sociology|Media(\s|-|)Studies',repl,teststring.replace('.',' ').strip(),flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'Legal Studies 131 race relations in the U S'
```

Comment: Damn it, I'm checking out the first example now; but the second example seems like it might be doing what I'm trying to do but just in the reverse order?   But I get lost with the "repl" use, so I (at the moment) can't figure out how to adjust it if that is the case, since repl can't be the first argument.

Comment: `repl` is a method called to provide the replacement each time it finds a search string eg. `'legal studies'` . All it does is find each word in the `match` and joins it by spaces. This is needed if the word contains hyphens as you have used in your example. Then it turns it into a title (the first letter of each word capitalized). It returns this as the replacement.

Comment: I just noticed you have updated the question so it may not work where words aren't separated by anything but that wasn't in the original example.

Comment: The problem (as I'm understanding it) isn't (or at least isn't yet) that it doesn't work with separated words; it's that the capitalization isn't meant to just be .title() case of the input, no?  (That part was in the first question as well)

Comment: From the dictionary of replacements i have they are all in title case.

Comment: Damn, this is why I need to start listening to people like Jack and actually give enough information in my posts!  Sorry to have done that to you.  I don't know if I shouldtry to bump the question for this or look around elsewhere; but does anyone have an unnamed-variable-name form of doing this?  Some one-liner gold would be...preferable and hugely appreciated (for my brain, not necessarily speed).  Biggest problem (for all these methods, really, is that I seem to be having a hard time having it return itself.  Seems like there has to be some way to do this wtih listcomprehensions, lambda, et